# No rewards to block authors for validating transactions in a PoA chain

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, moonbeam, rewards, poa

1- I've built a custom chain with unified accounts that uses PoA as its consensus, but there's no addition to the validator's balance on the confirmation of a transaction even though I've set in my code to send `90%` of the transaction fees to the block authors.

Here's my implementation:

```
pub struct DealWithFees;
type NegativeImbalance = <Balances as Currency<AccountId>>::NegativeImbalance;

impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for DealWithFees {
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item=NegativeImbalance>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            // for fees, 10% to treasury, 90% to author
            let mut split = fees.ration(10, 90);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 100% (though this can be anything)
                tips.merge_into(&mut split.1);
            }
            // Treasury::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            Author::on_unbalanced(split.1);
        }
    }
}

pub struct Author;

impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for Author {
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance) {
        if let Some(author) = Authorship::author() {
            Balances::resolve_creating(&author, amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've called this `DealWithFees` struct in `pallet_transaction_payment` like this:

```
type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees>;
```

2- Secondly, is it possible to give custom rewards to the block authors on each block validation other than the tips and transaction fees?

Thanks.